# Customising the page number in ToC using titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, titletoc

I am using `titletoc` to customise the ToC. Right now there are three things I cannot solve (I guess, due to the fact that page number is typeset in a fixed-width box):

1. The `titlerule` doesn't fill till the page number.
2. If page number is too large, it exceeds into the right margin.
3. If the title is too long, it bumps into the page number.

Here is an illustration:
[image]

I have fixed the first issue with

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{0pt{}}
\makeatother
```

but the new problem appears

[image]

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{0pt{}}
\makeatother
\titlecontents{chapter}
    [1cm]
    {\vspace{1cm}\filright}
    {\large\sffamily\bfseries\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{1cm}}
    {\hspace{-1cm}}
    {\titlerule*[3pt]{.}\sffamily\bfseries\large\contentspage}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{one}

    Sample text

    \cleardoublepage

    \addtocounter{page}{1000}

    \chapter{two}

    \chapter{a long long long long long long long long long long long long long  title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\p@numwidth}{0pt}` Really? Leaving no space for the page number box?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer David Carlisle suggested this as a solution to my first issue in one question on this site

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I could obtain with the tools from `titletoc`. It solves  points 2 and 3.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{1cm}
\titlecontents{chapter}
    [0.6cm]
    {\vspace{1cm}\filright\large\sffamily\bfseries}
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{1.3em}}
    {\hspace{-1cm}}
    {{\mdseries\hspace{0.4em}\titlerule*[6pt]{.}}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{one}

    Sample text

    \cleardoublepage

    \addtocounter{page}{1000}

    \chapter{two}

    \chapter{a long long long long long long long long long long long long long long title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like this works. Can everything be achieved with another package?

Comment: I guess `tocloft` can do it, but I don't know it well enough to be sure. As I use `titlesec`, I prefer to stick to the companion packages `titletoc` and `titleps`.

Comment: to my knowledge, `tocloft` is less powerfull. And I also use `titlesec`, so `tocloft` is the choice

Comment: @MichaelFraiman: `tocloft` is less powerful? That's a matter of choice. `tocloft` and `titletoc` however should not be used together.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer can this be made with `tocloft`?